# Cannot delete From: addresses in Exchange 2010 OWA's

Tags: exchange, outlook-web-app

I'm trying to clear the cache in the from: field of Exchange 2010 OWA. The user had send as permission to an account that does not have anymore, and I can't remove the cache.

I'm attaching a picture of the problem. Pressing Delete, Fn+Delete, Backspace in the OWA only works with the To: field. Not in From: field.

[image: cap]

How to delete those three address?

Answer (score 0):

[According to Microsoft](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/160/t/47397.aspx), the thing to do is to reattach the mailbox and then remove the `send as` permission to make that go away.  If that's not an option, you could remove the permission manually, though that's a fair bit more involved, and there's no telling what fun little issues that might create down the line.